# How to handle this checkbox?

Tags: angular, checkbox

im currently trying to "check" a value in a checkbox if the data from my database is matching. My problem is that my database output comes in a array like this:

```html
(console.log)
[{…}]
0:
fachbetreuung:
betreuer: "DMC\\bianca.nemitz"
bezeichnung: "SCM" //thats the value i need
fachbetreuungId: "72415569-6599-4bf2-a82b-a4124a610f75"
fachbetreuungPersonenzuordnungens: []
```

So i need the value named "bezeichnung". My problem is now that i need to read every single element of this array and then set the value in my checkbox like this:

this.fachBetreuerType[0].fachbetreuung.bezeichnung

I tried to reach it like that:

```html
<mat-checkbox *ngFor="let bezeichnung of betreuerOverview" 
                        [checked]="fachBetreuerType.fachbetreuung.bezeichnung"> <!-- This is the one-->
                        {{bezeichnung.bezeichnung}}
</mat-checkbox>
```

But if i try it like that, angular cant reach the value of the array and logs me "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bezeichnung')". I was thinking about a for loop as a solution but i dont know where i can place it? Into "checked" dont make sense i think.

//EDIT:

```html
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      const id = params['id'];
      this.fService
      .getFachInfos(id)
      .subscribe(data => { this.fachBetreuerType = data; console.log(this.fachBetreuerType);
      })}
    )
```

```html
getFachInfos(fachId:number){
    return this.http.get<FachbetreuungZuordnungSharing[]>(this.fBZ + fachId);
  }
```

Image of the Content:

https://ibb.co/xGWtLVs

Comment: Can you please add more code that shows how you assign values to `this.fachBetreuerType`? I suspect the data is not yet there when you try to access the first element of the array.

Comment: Edited now, there is how to assign and the specific output of it

Answer (score 0):

The data is fetched asynchronously, so you need to prevent the error while the data is still not there. You can try to do it something like this:

```html
<mat-checkbox
  *ngFor="let bezeichnung of betreuerOverview"
  [checked]="fachBetreuerType?.length && fachBetreuerType[0].fachbetreuung.bezeichnung">
  {{ bezeichnung.bezeichnung }}
</mat-checkbox>
```

This will check your checkbox for any [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value that `bezeichnung` has, which is probably not what you want. You should add further checks to make sure the checkbox is checked according to your business logic.

E.g:

```html
[checked]="fachBetreuerType?.length && fachBetreuerType[0].fachbetreuung.bezeichnung === 'SCM'"
```

Comment: Dont works, everything is selected with this. And also it dont make much sense, because a user can have multiple and different values, so not every user got the "SCM" but ty!

Answer (score 0):

As your data is coming from an API, it means when you try to reach out to "bezeichnung" or "fachBetreuerType", data haven't been loaded yet.

Your options to fix the problem depending on its source:

1- If the problem comes from "betreuerOverview", you can use *ngIf statement, but you won't be able to use it in the same place you put *ngFor. You have to wrap it with:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="betreuerOverview.length">
  <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let bezeichnung of betreuerOverview" 
                    [checked]="fachBetreuerType.fachbetreuung.bezeichnung"> <!-- This is the one-->
                    {{bezeichnung.bezeichnung}}
  </mat-checkbox>
</ng-container>
```

A more elegant way would be to simply initialize "betreuerOverview" with "[]", that way it won't iterate over it until there is data in it, and you won't have to use *ngIf conditional structure.

2- If the problem comes from "fachBetreuerType" being empty, you should test "fachBetreuerType" value in your ngIf statement then

```
<ng-container *ngIf="fachBetreuerType?.length">
  <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let bezeichnung of betreuerOverview" 
                [checked]="fachBetreuerType.fachbetreuung.bezeichnung"> <!-- This is the one-->
                {{bezeichnung.bezeichnung}}
  </mat-checkbox>
</ng-container>
```

Concerning test inside ngIf statement: it could be replaced by a more verbose test: "fachBetreuerType && fachBetreuerType.length > 0" for example, depends on your coding style.

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: The problem is still there, yes my data comes from a web api. That the data is not loaded is not a problem, because if im trying to console.log this: console.log(this.fachBetreuerType.fachbetreuung.bezeichnung); in the subscription im getting already a error.

Comment: Do you mind to copy paste your error message please ?